# What do you call the act of preventing a business from continuing?

Tags: grammar

> Shake And Shake was a Ponzi scheme and the SEC closed the business.

> The SEC closes Shake and Shake after repeated fraud allegations

Is "close" the only word, or is there a better way to say this?

Comment: Prefer **closed down** or **shut down**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the SEC issues closure orders and cease and deist orders.

So, your sentence could be something like:

> The SEC has ordered the closure of Shake and Shake after repeated fraud allegations.

or

> The SEC has issued a cease and desist order to Shake and Shake...

Answer (score 0):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cease_and_desist

Also consider, the issuance of a "cease and desist" document.